# Find the lowest multiplication between two numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, inequality

> > The sum of two numbers is less than $120$ with  he first number is bigger than the second. The differences (subtraction) between the two numbers is $60$. Find the lowest result of multiplication between the two numbers.

This is an easy question, but I can't seemed to solve this one. Anyway, from the question we obtained:

$$ a+b<120$$
$$a-b=60$$
And
$$a>b$$

---

As if it normal equations, I would have solve them easily. Any suggestions?

Comment: $a,b$ are integers or naturals or else?

Comment: @VikrantDesai they are integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to minimize $ab$. Since $a-b = 60 \implies a=60+b$, then minimizing $ab$ is the same as minimizing $(60+b)b$.

Using calculus, we can find any local minimums by setting the derivative of this equal to $0$ and solving for $b$,
$$\frac{d}{dx} (60+b)b = 0$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} 60b+b^2 = 0$$
$$ 60+2b = 0$$
$$b = -30$$

And thus $a = 60+b = 60-30 = 30$.

And thus the multiplication of the two is minimized at $ab = (30)(-30) = -90$.